# unable use "Split large virtual services and destination rules into multiple resources"

Tags: istio

istio document dercribe "Split large virtual services and destination rules into multiple resources"

https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/

this is my virtualService yaml ，

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: project-b
  namespace: test1
spec:
  hosts:
  - project-b.test1.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        route-namespace:
          exact: "test1"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: project-b.test1.svc.cluster.local


---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: project-b-test2
  namespace: test1
spec:
  hosts:
  - project-b.test1.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        route-namespace:
          exact: "test2"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: project-b.test2.svc.cluster.local
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8idx.png)
 just one virtural service is availabe,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected behavior.

According to [istio](https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/#split-virtual-services) documentation:

> In situations where it is inconvenient to define the complete set of route rules or policies for a particular host in a single `VirtualService` or `DestinationRule` resource, it may be preferable to incrementally specify the configuration for the host in multiple resources. **Pilot will merge such destination rules and merge such virtual services if they are bound to a gateway.**

---

> When a second and subsequent  `VirtualService`  for an existing host is applied,  `istio-pilot`  will merge the additional route rules into the existing configuration of the host. There are, however, several caveats with this feature that must be considered carefully when using it.
>
> 1. Although the order of evaluation for rules in any given source  `VirtualService`  will be retained, the cross-resource order is UNDEFINED. In other words, there is no guaranteed order of evaluation for rules across the fragment configurations, so it will only have predictable behavior if there are no conflicting rules or order dependency between rules across fragments.
> 2. There should only be one “catch-all” rule (i.e., a rule that matches any request path or header) in the fragments. All such “catch-all” rules will be moved to the end of the list in the merged configuration, but since they catch all requests, whichever is applied first will essentially override and disable any others.
> 3. A  `VirtualService`  can only be fragmented this way if it is bound to a gateway. Host merging is not supported in sidecars.